# Redirect root and subdomains to new url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

This might be simple but I am struggling to get it working for all scenarios.

I need to achieve the following redirects using htaccess:

https://example.com -> https://newdomain.com *(ignoring any requests to subpages)*

[https://example.com/ford/{anything}](https://example.com/ford/%7Banything%7D) -> https://newdomain.com/specificpage *(should redirect requests to /ford as well as e.g. /ford/frood, /ford/hoopy/frood etc)*

[https://example.com/arthur/{anything}](https://example.com/arthur/%7Banything%7D) -> https://newdomain.com/anotherpage *(should redirect requests to /arthur as well as e.g. /arthur/tea, /arthur/dressing/gown etc)*

[https://example.com/zaphod/{anything}](https://example.com/zaphod/%7Banything%7D) -> https://newdomain.com/differentpage *(should redirect requests to /zaphod as well as e.g. /zaphod/president, /zaphod/gargle/blaster etc)*

Happy to show my work so far but as it isn't doing what it should I am not sure it is much use! Any help very much appreciated

Comment: Kindly do share your tried code/.htaccess rules file in your question(not my downvote btw), cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds pretty straight forward, especially when you don't want to keep path and query information, which is what I understand from your question:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?ford/ https://newdomain.com/specificpage [R=301,L,QSD]
RewriteRule ^/?arthur/ https://newdomain.com/anotherpage [R=301,L,QSD]
RewriteRule ^/?zaphod/ https://newdomain.com/differentpage [R=301,L,QSD]
RewriteRule ^ ?https://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L,QSD]
```

In general you should prefer to implement such rules in the central http server's host configuration for the "example.com" domain. If you do not have access to that (read: if you are using a cheap hosting provider), then you can use a *distributed* configuration file instead (often called ".htaccess"). You need to enable to interpretation of such files beforehand (read about the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation) and you need to place that configuration file in the hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder, where it has to be readable for the http server process.